# Dimensions definition?

Tags: general-topology, definition

Apparently dimension is "informally" defined as ["the minimum number of coordinates needed to specify any point within it"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension). For example we need at least 3 numbers to describe any point in the 3D space and 4 numbers for 4D, etc.

However, since that $|\mathbb{R}^2| = |\mathbb{R}^3|$, therefore there must exist a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$, which also implies that 2 numbers are enough to describe all points within the 3D space, which is sort of surprising to me.

If we can use 2 number of coordinates to specify any point in 3D, then we can do the same thing for any other dimensions. This doesn't match the definition of dimension.

Is there anything incorrect in my logic, or is it that the definition of dimension is more complicated than the one I stated above?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate, definitely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912825/are-dimensions-redundant

Comment: @AsafKaragila - It's related, but I believe my question is more about the definition of dimension.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are different kinds of dimension. That's why the article starts off with an informal definition.

Comment: But what you say is just the fact that dimension is not a set-theoretical concept. Indeed, you should change the category "set-theory" to something like linear algebra, geometry, manifolds, or so.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1076332/4280

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah there is a bijective function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and you can say that $|\mathbb{R}^2| = |\mathbb{R}^3|$. However when you talk about dimension the algebraic structure joins the game. $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are considered as vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. To say that they are equivalent you need special kind of bijection $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $, such that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(ax) = af(x)$. Unfortunately such bijection does not exist. The thing that breaks your logic is the structure!

Comment: Actually... this is wrong. Assuming the axiom of choice, there is a $\Bbb Q$-linear isomorphism between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^4$ and in fact any $\Bbb Q$-vector space of cardinality continuum (which include many many many examples, from $\Bbb{R^N}$ to $\ell_2$, to the $p$-adic numbers).

Comment: Actually you are wrong @AsafKaragila , because the question is about $\mathbb{R}$-linear isomorphisms, since Derek is talking about finite dimension!

Comment: I see now that you implicitly refer to $\Bbb R$-linear isomorphisms.

Comment: I'd say "fortunately" rather than :"unfortunately".